# Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open my project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

After opening xcode, when I open my current project, it's showing a warning like "xcode quit unexpectedly" with 3 options: "Ignore", "Report" and "Reopen". When I click "Reopen", it will open the xcode window and again automatically it will close and show the same warning.

Why this is happening? If I open any other projects, then it opens with no issues; the issue is with my current app.

versions:

- xcode is 4.3.1
- mac OS X version is 10.7.3

Please tell me why it's happening like this.

Comment: rewove all user data from the project and try again. also, provide some error message - otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Try deleting DerivedData folder of your Current App. It should be located somewhere in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CurrentApp-{some generated string}/

Comment: I tried this but no result ..Same problem...shal i post problem report??

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Xcode stores some user state information inside the Xcode project “file”, which is really a folder.  That state information might have become corrupted.  You can normally throw away everything inside your `.xcodeproj` folder **except** the `project.pbxproj` file.  This might fix your problem.

Open up the folder containing your `.xcodeproj` file.  Right-click or control-click the `.xcodeproj` file and choose “Show Package Contents”.  Then throw away everything except the `project.pbxproj` file.

[image: cleaning an xcodeproj package]

If you know what an Xcode workspace is, and you're actually making use of it, you might not have a `project.xcworkspace` file to throw away, or you might not want to throw it away.  But if you don't know what an Xcode workspace is, then you're not using it so you can just throw away `project.xcworkspace`.  Xcode will recreate it automatically.

Comment: You are the man ! I personaly went on `biogaran.xcworkspace` and removed the folder `xcuserdata`

Comment: Nice graphic but this didn't fix it for me-!! My issue was xcodes built in version control - solved by http://stackoverflow.com/a/18914491/1061800

Comment: Its not solving my problem yet. i am able to open xcode 8 but in xcode 7 still getting same alert again and again.

Comment: After doing this I had recreate my build schemes in order to build and run.

Comment: I was using a workspace - did the same thing on my .workspace file and it worked :)

Comment: Deleting just **UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate** file fixed the issue

Comment: It might also help to download a fresh git clone of the project - if the xcuserdata etc are ignored, you should get a clean version. helped here.

Answer (score 19):

Deleting Derived Data worked for me. Just open another project or open xcode without opening your corrupted project. Than open preferences and go locations tab at the end. Click gray circle with arrow (where all your projects derived data are saved.)[image]

Delete your corrupted project's derived data in there and you are good to go.

Comment: worked for me as well, thanks! Deleting files in *.xcodeproj directory did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

you can run XcodeSystemResources.pkg.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg.
```

I hope help to you

Answer (score 6):

go to [ProjectName].xcworkspace file.Right click. Show package contents. Delete xcuserdata folder. After deleting, run the project it will work for sure.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend opening the terminal and copying in the following:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

**Note:** credit to zirinisp for providing [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8) that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the Xcode saved state. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am using CocoaPod (XCode 8.2), these steps solved my issue:

1. Go to project folder
2. Open package contents of .xcworkspace
3. Delete xcuserdata in package contents
4. Remove it from Trash (optional)
5. Go back and open .xcworkspace (XCode will prompt to reopen, but don't do this)
6. Continue with your project :)

Answer (score 2):

Open project folder show package contents from .**xcworkspace** or .**xcodeproj** You will see 2 folders **xcshareddata** and **xcuserdata** Please remove **xcuserdata** folder Try to open application

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **CocoaPods**, just follow Rob's instruction but on the **.xcworkspace** file instead and do not delete the **.xcworkspacedata** file.

Comment: You're right but they can make clean cocoapods installation if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My Solved that worked

1. Go to project folder
2. open package contents of .xcodeproject
3. Delete xcuserdata in package contents
4. Go back and delete .xcworkspace

/// Please dont delete .pbxproj

Try to open your project and work  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's 2021, still having this problem. Reboot doesn't help, OS update doesn't help.

Then I updated everything in the App Store (iMovie, Numbers, Pages, Keynote) and Xcode is now working.

Please don't ask why.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CocoaPods, and followed Rob's Instruction on the .xcworkspace file as indicated above by Allecto. After I "showed Package Contents" on the .xcworkspace file, the only thing I did was to rename the xcuserdata folder to xcuserdataCrashApril2. I was then able to open the project (workspace) with no problems. The only difference is xcode did not save the state of which .swift source code files were previously opened (which is not a big issue for me).

I suppose I can delete the xcuserdataCrashApril2 file, but I am keeping it out there as a reminder of what to do the next time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Xcode 8.3**

Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`

Delete Derived Data folder and it works for me.

May help you.

Answer (score 0):

All the advices from above didn't help me so I added the pod file via pod init & pod install and successfully opened newly created .xcworkspace. Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

I also have this bug with XCode 10.3. In my case i launch app -> it displays alert "Quits unexpectedly" and it doesn't matter what i choose: to reopen or not - it crashes again.

**Solution: Reboot Mac :))**

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete Project.xcworkspace first.
2. Open Terminal
3. Go to application folder
4. Run command pod install
5. Delete Derived Data
6. Open Project.xcworkspace

It works for me.