# Xcode quit unexpectedly when opening my project

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, quit

I tried to delete the 2 files in the projects package content and if I do that my project works but when I click on any file it quits again

```
log:

Process:               Xcode [515]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.4 (7720)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7720000000000000~8
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812725084
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [515]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-04 12:34:07.199 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        93354AAB-2902-3F8B-27E6-05F9AFC1C64D


Time Awake Since Boot: 580 seconds

Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: IBPlatformToolRequestQueue.IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: This isn't geared toward solving your immediate problem, but do you know how to use Git? If not, I would back up a step and learn how to use it if you're just starting out learning to code. It will save you massive amounts of time and frustration down the road.

Comment: am fine with coding i dont mind using Git but i need a solution for my dumb xcode

Answer (score 2):

Whenever this has happened to me, i keep Xcode closed and delete DerivedData folder. This is located at /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Try restarting your machine after deleting derivedData

Comment: samething this didnt fix it :/

Comment: What 2 files did you delete?

Comment: xcuserdata and project.xcworkspace in the package content as its shown here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project)

Comment: I would suggest getting them out of trash and putting them back in. That answer is from 3 years ago and i would assume that the inner workings of Xcode has changed since then and this could cause problems

Answer (score -1):

Deleting Derived data and clearing cache helps
you can clear derived data by pressing CMD+, in xcode and select locations then click the little gray arrow beneath Derived data and select the derived data folder and just select and trash

You can clear cache by pressing CMD+k

Comment: Merely repeats the existing answer.