# Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

when i open xcode version 7.3.1 show this message
"Xcode quits unexpectedly"

i test this command

1. sudo  gem install cocoapods
2. sudo /Aplication/Xcode.../xcode

i see this link but not working for me
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project)

my current os : Yosemite  Version 10.90

but show this dialog

log:

```
2016-05-13 14:08:10.489 Xcode[4837:85855] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-10117/InterfaceBuilderKit/WidgetIntegration/IBIntegratorManager.m:318

Details:  Failed to find integrator bundle for class IBAbstractViewController

Object:   <IBIntegratorManager: 0x7fe3cb775320>

Method:   -registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:

Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe3cb43f480>{number = 1, name = main}

Hints:   None

2016-05-13 14:08:10.509 Xcode[4837:85855] [MT] DVTAssertions: 

Backtrace:
 0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)

  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)

  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)

  3   -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  4   -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  5   -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrators:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  6   -[IBIntegratorManager loadAllIntegrators] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  7   -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  8   +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)

  9   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)

 10   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)

 11   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)

 12   __IDEInitialize_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)

 13   IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice (in IDEFoundation)

 14   -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] (in IDEKit)

 15   -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] (in IDEKit)

 16   -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] (in IDEKit)

 17   -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] (in AppKit)

 18   __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)

 19   __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 (in AppKit)

 20   -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)

 21   -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)

 22   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] (in AppKit)

 23   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] (in AppKit)

 24   -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in Foundation)

 25   -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in IDEKit)

 26   _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler (in Foundation)

 27   aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) (in AE)

 28   dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) (in AE)

 29   aeProcessAppleEvent (in AE)

 30   AEProcessAppleEvent (in HIToolbox)

 31   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)

 32   -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)

 33   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)

 34   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)

 35   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)

 36  0x000000010c71739b (in Xcode)

 37   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Comment: What's the assertion text?  Also why are you running `sudo Xcode`?

Comment: I still don't understand why `sudo Xcode`?

Comment: i test any way
first time execute xcode from applications

 i think need to permission 
and execute with sudo

and test other way who existed on google

Comment: It's not normally how you start Xcode and I don't see the value.  There are ways of getting privilege escalation if you want to run processes as root and running Xcode as root is not it.

Comment: i dont underestand.  i want execute xcode .  what to do ??? tnx .

Comment: Don't start it from the command line.  Don't use `sudo`.  Click on the Xcode icon in the Dock or use Cmd-Space and type "Xcode".

Comment: test tow way . again show this message . "Xcode quits unexpectedly "

Comment: show log in details:
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-10117/InterfaceBuilderKit/WidgetIntegration/IBIntegratorManager.m:318
Details:  Failed to find integrator bundle for class IBStoryboardGlobalEntryPointIndicator

Answer (score 3):

Just delete  XCode saved state. It worked for me.
How to do this ? lets try

**Navigate to ~/Library/Saved Application State/**

– this is easy with ***Command+Shift+G***

after navigating to saved application folder 
You’ll see a list of saved app states named com.apple.(Application Name).savedState

Delete the folder named **com.apple.dt.xcode.savedState**

Enjoy xcode again :)

Comment: After deleting savedState. go to [ProjectName].xcworkspace file.Right click. Show package contents. Delete xcuserdata folder. After that xcode opens regularly.