# Xcode 8.2.1 becomes unresponsive when i click on main.Storyboard

Tags: xcode

First, there's one old question with the same issue, but since the answers don't work for me, i'm posting this one:

I had problems to open an old project at all. So i deleted xcuserdata and the derived data, from the options tab, too. This one worked fine and i was able to open the project, but now when i click on the storyboard Xcode "hangs" and i have to force it to quit.

This happens only if i click on main.Storyboard, every other file in the project works fine when i click on it.

The last thing i tried was to run the project and in the last 5 minutes, it says Compiling 2 of 2 Storyboard files and that's all; no other result at the moment.

edit: cleaning the project doesn't work too.

edit2: It seems the problem is with my Xcode, not the project. I created a new project and Xcode freeze when i try to open the storyboard. Same with some other old projects.
Next step: reinstalling the Xcode.

Comment: What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: i'm using Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, like i comment previously, i tried a lot of things before consider to reinstall Xcode, but the most important were to run the project in other Mac and when i saw that there was no problem to show the storyboard i concluded that the issue were in Xcode.

I reinstalled it and it works fine.

Before everyone does that it's probably a good idea to see if your project run on other mac.
You can also delete [xcuserdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600567/5843195), the [derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107490/5843195) and the [Xcode saved state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863543/5843195).

Among the other things i tried:
I restored the version of main.storyboard i have on time machine, just before the crash. Didn't worked, but worth to try.
I also considered to replace the file with the same but from some old version. But the problem was, that i've made too many changes on the actual storyboard, so i needed to find a way to restore it.