# Xcode unexpectedly quit while reopening windows every time

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode7.3

Every time i am opening **Xcode 7.3.1**. I am getting error in pop-up **"The last time you opened Xcode, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?"** and whatever option you select, Xcode automatically crash and closed and on reopening it again showing the same message every time. This could be possible duplicate question but i am not able to find out the solution. What i have tried

1. Delete and reinstall Xcode 7.3.1 again
2. Delete and install another version Xcode 7.2
3. Update the OS form El capitan to OS sierra
4. Deleted the Xcuserdata form .xcodeproj as mention here
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600567/3647325
5. Deleted the Drived data from `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
6. Deleted Xcode's preferences `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Comment: can you keep xcode 7.3.1 and try intalling xcode 8 ( keep both of them seperate )

Comment: @AmodGokhale i am able to open Xcode 8 but my all running project are in Swift 2.2 So cannot convert all to in swift 2.2 or 3. so quickly.

Comment: can you try to supress the alert? try this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80900/suppressing-reopen-windows-dialog-when-restarting-a-crashed-program-in-mountai

Comment: @AmodGokhale  Dude Thanks! Its worked for me ..You really saved my weekend.

Comment: upvote original answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same issue with Xcode 8.1 and tried the above answer also. Still it didn't get fixed. After trying for few hours what I did was, opened an earlier version of the Xcode (7.3) and then it also showed the same message. But when I selected Reopen option it opened properly. Then I closed it and opened the Xcode 8.1 and it opened without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by just starting xcode which needed an update.