# Xcode 8.2.1 quits unexpectedly every time when I open my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm getting an error Xcode 8.2.1 quit unexpectedly whenever Xcode is opened. This was working fine till last night. I have tried restart system but didn't worked.I have updated mac OS with macOS Sierra (version 10.12.3).

I already deleted derived data from preferences but it's not working for me.

please tell me why its happening like this...Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project)

Comment: I tried all these 3 answers but not able to open Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this situation before.

My solution is that:

1. quit Xcode clearly
2. open other no question project or create a new project
3. open the your project again which will quit unexpectedly

it's maybe Xcode's bug, this is work to me, hope it's work to you too!

Comment: I'm not able to create new Project because Xcode is not responding anything. It's just open, loading and close.

Answer (score 1):

That state information might have become corrupted.

**Follow these steps hope it will help you**

1.) Right click on your project.

2.) Choose package content.

3.) Delete all extra files except `project.pbxproj`

4.) Come back to your project.

5.) Run