# MacInCloud - Xcode quits unexpectedly (10.3)

Tags: ios, xcode

Using MacInCloud's managed server.

Tried opening another example project downloaded on Github, doesn't work.
Tried everything here: [Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project)
None of them worked.

Full stack trace on Gist: https://gist.github.com/topherseance/e733af8a420682b20d423a6bd57b3d5e
Snippet of the stack trace (omitted because it's too long to fit in SO question)

```
Process:               Xcode [26214]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.3 (14492.2)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14492002000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832020435
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [26214]
User ID:               597

Date/Time:             2019-09-21 01:39:45.391 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6EFBD89B-405E-274D-2EDB-E2B334A57DD8


Time Awake Since Boot: 85000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: DVTPlugInExtensionFaultingLock

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 10G8
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Extension Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.ImageKitIntegration.Integrator.IKImageBrowserView class 'IKImageBrowserView' not found for required key 'integratedClass'
UserInfo: {
    DVTExtensionClassNameErrorKey = IKImageBrowserView;
    DVTExtensionIdentifierErrorKey = "Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.ImageKitIntegration.Integrator.IKImageBrowserView";
    DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.framework";
    DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey = "com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration";
}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[DVTExtension _adjustClassAttribute:forKey:inParameterData:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4   -[DVTExtension _adjustClassReferencesInParameterData:usingSchema:] (in DVTFoundation)
  5   -[DVTExtension _fireExtensionFault:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6   __63-[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:error:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  7   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
 10   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 11   -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
 13   -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrators:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14   -[IBIntegratorManager loadAllIntegrators] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15   -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16   +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
 18   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
 19   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
 20   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
 21   __IDEInitialize_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 22   __IDERunBlockWhenSafeToLoadMobileDevice_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 23   IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice (in IDEFoundation)
 24   -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _prepareXcodeForUIWithRegistrationAndSetupOfExtraServices:] (in IDEKit)
 25   -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] (in IDEKit)
 26   -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] (in IDEKit)
 27   -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] (in IDEKit)
 28   -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] (in AppKit)
 29   __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 30   __90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 31   -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 32   __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 (in AppKit)
 33   -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 34   -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 35   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] (in AppKit)
 36   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] (in AppKit)
 37   -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in Foundation)
 38   -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] (in IDEKit)
 39   _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler (in Foundation)
 40   aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) (in AE)
 41   dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) (in AE)
 42   aeProcessAppleEvent (in AE)
 43   AEProcessAppleEvent (in HIToolbox)
 44   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 45   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 46   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 47   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 48   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 49   main (in Xcode)
 50   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInternalInconsistencyException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff475ca439 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
1   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101a474f6 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 274
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff71d413c6 objc_exception_throw + 48
3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101870dd0 -[DVTExtension _adjustClassAttribute:forKey:inParameterData:] + 711
4   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101871419 -[DVTExtension _adjustClassReferencesInParameterData:usingSchema:] + 482
5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010187192e -[DVTExtension _fireExtensionFault:] + 494
6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010186f600 __63-[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:error:]_block_invoke + 245
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff734b963d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff734c5129 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101a91fec DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 208
10  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101a67ffa -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 73
11  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010186f153 -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:error:] + 495
12  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010186f948 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] + 179
13  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000011a6defd8 -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrators:] + 388
14  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000011a6df7db -[IBIntegratorManager loadAllIntegrators] + 173
15  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000011a6e18c6 -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] + 329
16  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000011a6e1763 +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] + 34
17  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288fe90 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 2283
18  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288f7c4 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 543
19  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288f7c4 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 543
20  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288e6c4 _IDEInitializePlugIns + 1404
21  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288df21 __IDEInitialize_block_invoke + 46
22  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288e9fc __IDERunBlockWhenSafeToLoadMobileDevice_block_invoke + 97
23  IDEFoundation                       0x000000010288ef1a IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice + 286
24  IDEKit                              0x000000010359d18d -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _prepareXcodeForUIWithRegistrationAndSetupOfExtraServices:] + 232
25  IDEKit                              0x000000010359cf97 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] + 494
26  IDEKit                              0x000000010359ccd5 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] + 27
27  IDEKit                              0x00000001034e4537 -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] + 247
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b02202 -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] + 429
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b01cfe __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke + 234
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b01a7a __90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 66
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b019af -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:] + 342
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b01831 __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 95
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b01416 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] + 722
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b00c69 -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:completionHandler:] + 249
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b00a5e -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 539
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff44b006bb -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 688
37  Foundation                          0x00007fff497d4700 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 286
38  IDEKit                              0x0000000103502351 -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 101
39  Foundation                          0x00007fff497d457d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
40  AE                                  0x00007fff48756397 _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 1815
41  AE                                  0x00007fff48755c29 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 41
42  AE                                  0x00007fff48755b01 aeProcessAppleEvent + 414
43  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff4676d8b7 AEProcessAppleEvent + 54
44  AppKit                              0x00007fff44afcabd _DPSNextEvent + 1935
45  AppKit                              0x00007fff44afb48b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
46  DVTKit                              0x000000010206a962 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 385
47  AppKit                              0x00007fff44af55a8 -[NSApplication run] + 699
48  AppKit                              0x00007fff44ae4ae8 NSApplicationMain + 777
49  Xcode                               0x00000001017c78a2 main + 578
50  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff735063d5 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: DVTPlugInExtensionFaultingLock
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff736412c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fcbf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff735ab6a6 abort + 127
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000103500b37 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1324
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001035021f9 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 1094
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001035022cf IDEHandleUncaughtException + 94
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4763ed1d __handleUncaughtException + 775
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff71d43775 _objc_terminate() + 91
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff7079c19e std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff7079c213 std::terminate() + 51
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b9651 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734c5129 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
12  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101a91fec DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 208
13  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101a67ffa -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 73
14  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010186f153 -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:error:] + 495
15  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010186f948 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] + 179
16  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011a6defd8 -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrators:] + 388
17  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011a6df7db -[IBIntegratorManager loadAllIntegrators] + 173
18  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011a6e18c6 -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] + 329
19  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011a6e1763 +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] + 34
20  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288fe90 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 2283
21  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288f7c4 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 543
22  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288f7c4 _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites + 543
23  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288e6c4 _IDEInitializePlugIns + 1404
24  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288df21 __IDEInitialize_block_invoke + 46
25  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288e9fc __IDERunBlockWhenSafeToLoadMobileDevice_block_invoke + 97
26  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010288ef1a IDESetSafeToLoadMobileDevice + 286
27  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010359d18d -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _prepareXcodeForUIWithRegistrationAndSetupOfExtraServices:] + 232
28  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010359cf97 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] + 494
29  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010359ccd5 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] + 27
30  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001034e4537 -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] + 247
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b02202 -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] + 429
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b01cfe __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke + 234
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b01a7a __90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 66
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b019af -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:] + 342
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b01831 __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 95
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b01416 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] + 722
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b00c69 -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:completionHandler:] + 249
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b00a5e -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 539
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44b006bb -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 688
40  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff497d4700 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 286
41  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000103502351 -[NSAppleEventManager(DVTAssertionOverrides) swizzleDispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 101
42  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff497d457d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
43  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff48756397 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 1815
44  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff48755c29 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 41
45  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff48755b01 aeProcessAppleEvent + 414
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4676d8b7 AEProcessAppleEvent + 54
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44afcabd _DPSNextEvent + 1935
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44afb48b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
49  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010206a962 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 385
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44af55a8 -[NSApplication run] + 699
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff44ae4ae8 NSApplicationMain + 777
52  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x00000001017c78a2 main + 578
53  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff735063d5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimServiceContext.profileQueue
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff736ee878 _platform_memcmp + 312
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff475d7149 __CFStringEqual + 239
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474dfaf5 CFBasicHashAddValue + 1205
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474e5cc3 CFDictionaryAddValue + 187
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750e601 __54-[CFPrefsSource mergeIntoDictionary:sourceDictionary:]_block_invoke + 22
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750e5ca __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750e3b6 CFBasicHashApply + 112
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750e32e CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 130
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750dfec -[CFPrefsSource mergeIntoDictionary:sourceDictionary:] + 128
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff47508981 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_getDictionary:] + 594
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4750845f -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 158
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff475083a7 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 47
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff47508365 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474f262e __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 268
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474f22f0 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 337
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474f2041 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 150
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474f1bff _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 107
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff474f1a1f _CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValueWithContainer + 31
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4979644b -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) boolForKey:] + 102
19  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x0000000111781ae0 _SimLogXPC + 205
20  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x00000001117336ce __72-[SimServiceContext _supportedDeviceTypesAddProfilesAtPath:allowRescan:]_block_invoke + 315
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b963d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734c5129 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
23  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x00000001117332e1 -[SimServiceContext _supportedDeviceTypesAddProfilesAtPath:allowRescan:] + 1035
24  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x0000000111736130 -[SimServiceContext addProfilesForDeveloperDir:] + 1386
25  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x000000011172e367 -[SimServiceContext initWithDeveloperDir:connectionType:error:] + 1309
26  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x000000011172dd02 __63+[SimServiceContext sharedServiceContextForDeveloperDir:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 187
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b963d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734c5129 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
29  com.apple.CoreSimulator         0x000000011172d8c5 +[SimServiceContext sharedServiceContextForDeveloperDir:error:] + 252
30  com.apple.DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient    0x0000000117b4a786 __60+[SimServiceContext(DVTAdditions) dvt_sharedServiceContext:]_block_invoke + 158
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b963d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734bad4b _dispatch_once_callout + 20
33  com.apple.DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient    0x0000000117b4a6a3 +[SimServiceContext(DVTAdditions) dvt_sharedServiceContext:] + 251
34  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore  0x0000000117a954bc __42-[DVTiPhoneSimulatorLocator startLocating]_block_invoke_2 + 112
35  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101a9143e __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 801
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b85f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734b963d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734bbde6 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734bb4a3 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734c73bc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 324
41  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff734c7b46 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 90
42  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f96b3 _pthread_wqthread + 583
43  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f93f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7363b22a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7363b76c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4751446d __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 327
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff475139da __CFRunLoopRun + 1619
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff47513135 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 459
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4979532f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 280
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000117b82de1 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 217
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4978b112 __NSThread__start__ + 1194
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fa2eb _pthread_body + 126
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fd249 _pthread_start + 66
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f940d thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7363b22a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7363b76c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4751446d __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 327
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff475139da __CFRunLoopRun + 1619
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff47513135 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 459
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4979532f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 280
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000117b90c5d -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 791
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff4978b112 __NSThread__start__ + 1194
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fa2eb _pthread_body + 126
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fd249 _pthread_start + 66
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f940d thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7364261a __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff47541988 __CFSocketManager + 630
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fa2eb _pthread_body + 126
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fd249 _pthread_start + 66
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f940d thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7363ef32 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff735ca914 nanosleep + 199
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolicationDT   0x00000001045076c8 cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 41
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fa2eb _pthread_body + 126
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736fd249 _pthread_start + 66
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff736f940d thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000001072285c0  rcx: 0x00007ffeee437028  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffeee437060  rsp: 0x00007ffeee437028
   r8: 0x0000000103d4ff60   r9: 0x0000000103b5e56c  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff736412c6  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fffa9b0d188

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
(omitted)

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 32019
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=847.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=847.6M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=147.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=147.7M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        1 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                  224K        2 
CoreImage                            8K        2 
CoreServices                      3328K        1 
CoreUI image data                   52K        1 
CoreUI image file                  196K        3 
Dispatch continuations            16.0M        1 
Foundation                           4K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           109.9M       47 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        1 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M       13 
Stack                             14.1M       13 
VM_ALLOCATE                         80K       10 
__DATA                            74.8M      538 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       289.4M      162 
__TEXT                           558.9M      522 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                      113.5M       23 
shared memory                     2680K       12 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G     1364 

Model: Macmini6,2, BootROM 280.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.8f1
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD4000Item, Intel HD Graphics 4000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.33 AirPortDriverBrcm4360-1325.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 PRO 512GB, 512.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD20SPZX-00CRAT0, 2 TB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: I am using 2018 Mac-Mini (i5 16GB Ram) as my work machine. It crashes out of no reason some times.   Are you  building large project? Are you experiencing frequents crashes? If not then sometimes critical process die due to heavy workload.

Comment: I'm building an Ionic3 project, it uses Cordova. This is the 1st time I logged in to my MacInCloud account, and can't start XCode anymore. I tried opening another sample XCode project from Github, still XCode won't open.

Comment: Contact support team @topher